# How to Use Proxy in Android App Java Code

Tags: java, android, proxy, proxyselector

I'm relatively new to Android programming and I am developing an app which needs its online traffic to go through a proxy.

1- I came across **Proxy** and **ProxySelector** in Android developer website but found very little on how and where exactly in my code to use them (I am writing Java).

2- I am concern that my users might abuse the proxy by using it for other purposes than what it is intended for. how could I ensure my app users won't be able to see or abuse the paid proxy?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: For second part: How exactly can users abuse the proxy? The word abuse has a broad meaning. How much control do you have over behavior of proxy? How does it behave? Is it vulnerable to MITM? Please provide some details.

Comment: @narendra-choudhary, The proxy has been supplied through a third-party company and I don't have any control over its behavior. If I could force proxy to only attend to requests for certain domains that would have been ideal, but I can't. The concern is if employees extract the proxy from the app and use it to get to restricted websites. The proxy being a paid one that could cause a bit of an issue (cost and bandwidth). Thanks